# Сравнить суммы чисел двух числовых промежутков

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 функции, одна подсчитывает сумму, вторая должна возвращать сравнение сумм по двум промежуткам(в данном случае от 5 до 15 и от 3 до 5)
Нужно найти сумму чисел на каждом промежутке и сравнить эти суммы. Если сумма чисел на первом промежутке больше - вернуть true, в другом случае вернуть false.

```
function sum(from, to) {
  let sum = 0;
for (let i = from; i <= to; i++){
sum += to;
}
return sum;
}

function compareSums(firstFrom, firstTo, secondFrom, secondTo) {
  sum(firstFrom, firstTo);
  sum(secondFrom, secondTo);
if (sum(firstFrom, firstTo) > sum(secondFrom, secondTo)){
return true;
}
return false;
}

compareSums(5, 15, 3, 5); // ===> true
```

Как бы эти функции связать между собой чтобы это работало? Хелп плиз..

Comment: Что не работает?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy У него всё работает. Просто очень хочется "связать" функции ;)

Comment: я подредактировал код, теперь то всё работает но проблема в том что мне тут система выдает ошибку что "Неверная логика работы sum". Помогите, как улучшить/исправить это?

Comment: @Ector Что за система? Какие требования? Вы добавили две строчки в compareSums(), но они лишние и бессмысленные.

Comment: да, ок. Уже разобрался со всем.

Answer (score -1):

Я связал Вам эти функции, насколько это было возможно:

```js
let a1 = 5, b1 = 15;
let a2 = 3, b2 = 5;

console.log(
  b1 * (b1 + 1) - a1 * (a1 - 1) > b2 * (b2 + 1) - a2 * (a2 - 1)
)
```

Comment: Минусующие, совсем без юмора?